# Is it safe to put lambdas in a static initializer list and capture by reference?

Tags: c++, reference, static, lambda, initializer-list

```
void func(const std::string& args)
{

    // Statically initialize a vector of lambdas (only one here for now)
    // The lambdas capture by reference with[&], but since the
    // initializer list is static (and thus initialized only once), how
    // will the lambda be able to access args with each successive call to func()?
    // Won't there be undefined behavior with this?
    static std::vector<std::function<void()>> FuncMap =
    {

        // args (and everything else in scope) will be captured by reference
        { [&]() { for(const auto& s: args) std::cout << s << std::endl; }}

    };

    auto f = FuncMap[0];

    f();
}
```

Comment: I'm learning to like c++11 :)

Comment: What you do here is capturing all variables in the *literal scope* of the lambda function. This includes `args` (by the way: shouldn't it be a vector?), `FuncMap` and everything we don't see in this code snippet. However, if the lambda function gets executed, the variables in the *execution scope* aren't captured at all, so it can safely passed around and you only have to worry about the variables captured when the function was *created*. That being said I'd recommend to write `[&args]` instead of `[&]` if you know exactly that you don't want to capture more than this.

Comment: See §5.1.2 (expr.prim.lambda) / 22 => this "is likely to result in undefined behavior" (likely?) as the original object which has been bound by reference has been destroyed on a second call to `f`.

Comment: @DyP: it depends on the caller of func(). args string is passed to func by reference too, so if the (first) caller of func() allocates the argument properly (with sufficient lifetime), the lambda should work.

Comment: @user396672 Sry, I overlooked `args` is passed by reference. Yet, I wouldn't do this that way at it _can_ easily lead to undefined behaviour.

Comment: @DyP: Surely, it's really error prone. Lamda with lifitime extending beyond its context should capture by value (it also may capture a shared_ptr to avoid copying)

Comment: @user396672 I absolutely agree. This reminds me of [Gotw #105](http://herbsutter.com/2012/06/05/gotw-105-smart-pointers-part-3-difficulty-710/). Ownership isn't expressed clear here IMHO, if the lambda captures the ref.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if you're asking this out of curiosity, or if you are actually trying to do something like this.  If the latter, here's a possible solution:

```
void func(const std::string& args)
{
    static std::string const * pargs;
    static std::vector<std::function<void()>> FuncMap =
    {        
        { [&]() { for(const auto& s: *pargs) std::cout << s << std::endl; }}
    };

    pargs = &args;
    auto f = FuncMap[0];

    f();
}
```

Comment: The reference to args stored in pargs won't be valid after func returns if args was not originally a std::string. (And it certainly won't be valid outside of the scope of func). In this case, where the retained lambda is called only once so capture isn't important, it doesn't matter, but then why go to the trouble of storing the lambda at all? Here's an example which shows both the problem and a possible solution: http://liveworkspace.org/code/6e55737883e306163ff994a984f793f1